# "limpar" texto escrito no input A e reescreve-lo no input B utilizando jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um `< input type="text" id="A" >`, gostaria que ao digitar um texto qualquer nesse input, ele fosse reescrito no input B, porém antes do texto ser reescrito, gostaria que ele passa-se por uma "limpeza". Essa limpeza é pra tirar os caracteres especiais do texto, e pra substituir o "espaços" por "-".

Atualmente já faço essa "limpeza" com php, só que não é algo dinâmico. Assim nem sempre o texto limpo fica da maneira que eu quero! Exemplo disso é a seguinte situação!

Antes:

```
"Esse é um TEXTO que ééu quero LIMpar! Verá ele limpo em Seguida!"
```

Depois

```
"esse-e-um-texto-que-eeu-quero-limpar--vera-ele-limpo-em-seguida-"
```

Agora com essa reescritura do texto eu vou poder controlar melhor o resultado final! Assim caso eu não goste eu vou poder editar o texto final antes mesmo de cadastrar no banco de dados.

O código php que uso pra limpar esse texto é:

```
$ltag = strtolower(preg_replace('{\W}', ' ', preg_replace('{ +}', ' ', strtr(utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($tag)), utf8_decode('ÀÁÃÂÉÊÍÓÕÔÚÜÇÑàáãâéêíóõôúüçñ'), 'AAAAEEIOOOUUCNaaaaeeiooouucn'))));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para fazer um `replaceAl`l em todos os "espaços" precisa implementar o restante é coisa simples, fiz um exemplo:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(de, para){
        var str = this;
        var pos = str.indexOf(de);
        while (pos > -1){
                    str = str.replace(de, para);
                    pos = str.indexOf(de);
            }
        return (str);
    };
    
    var teste ={};

    teste.limpar=function(){
        $('#A').keyup(function(){
            var aux = new String( $(this).val() );            
            aux = aux.replaceAll(" ","-").toLowerCase();
            aux = teste.replaceSpecialChars(aux);
            $("#B").val(aux);
        });
    };

/**
 * Array de objectos de qual caracter deve substituir seu par com acentos
 */
var specialChars = [
 {val:"a",let:"áàãâä"},
 {val:"e",let:"éèêë"},
 {val:"i",let:"íìîï"},
 {val:"o",let:"óòõôö"},
 {val:"u",let:"úùûü"},
 {val:"c",let:"ç"},
 {val:"A",let:"ÁÀÃÂÄ"},
 {val:"E",let:"ÉÈÊË"},
 {val:"I",let:"ÍÌÎÏ"},
 {val:"O",let:"ÓÒÕÔÖ"},
 {val:"U",let:"ÚÙÛÜ"},
 {val:"C",let:"Ç"},
 {val:"",let:"?!()"}
];
 
/**
 * Função para substituir caractesres especiais.
 * @param {str} string
 * @return String
 */
teste.replaceSpecialChars= function (str) {
 var $spaceSymbol = '-';
 var regex;
 var returnString = str;
 for (var i = 0; i < specialChars.length; i++) {
  regex = new RegExp("["+specialChars[i].let+"]", "g");
  returnString = returnString.replace(regex, specialChars[i].val);
  regex = null;
 }
 return returnString.replace(/\s/g,$spaceSymbol);
};

    teste.limpar();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="A" />
<input type="text" id="B" />
```

A parte da expressão regular segue o link http://snipplr.com/view/15532/replace-de-caracteres-especiais-por-seu-equivalente-sem-acento/

Testado com Chrome em:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/sneeps_ninja/wxse2p7u/1/